# After getting matched correspondences in SIFT feature matching in matlab, how to get the location of that matched object?

Tags: matlab

I have implemented SIFT in matlab and also getting the matching correspondences between template and object in image. But, I am wondering how to get the location of that matched object in the image. Also tried RANSAC but I am getting orientation and scale information only.

Comment: Once they are matched, you know where it is,no?

Comment: Like I am getting several matching correspondences and by using those correspondences, how can I get the location or centroid? Should I take the average of location of all correspondences?

Comment: That is indeed, the definition of the centroid.

Comment: But I am wondering if accuracy can be achieved in presence of outliers.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by accuracy. For a lot of applications, always, for other applicatiosn never, there are a lot of applications where the answer is sometimes.